# Excel VBA: Add user form controls to selected worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I don't know how to code this and I also don't know how to explain this but I wish it is understandable.

I have a user form and I want the controls on that user form be added to a selected worksheet. I think I should loop through all the controls then add its labels to a selected worksheet without having to specify what cell this label will be added to every time. How should I code this?

I'm not really sure if my explanation is understandable so please bear with me. Thank you.

Comment: So do you want controls on one sheet or the values of it?

Comment: The names of the controls? Specifically the labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the names of the controls try this:

```
Dim c As Control
For Each c In UserForm1.Controls
    i = i + 1
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = c.Name
Next
```

EDIT: 
For label captions.

```
Dim c As Control
For Each c In UserForm1.Controls
    If TypeName(c) = "Label" Then
    i = i + 1
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = c.Caption
    End If
 Next
```

Comment: In order for this to work, it must be in a form event. Otherwise the Me will not be the form.

Comment: `.Caption` is a property only for labels and would return whats written in the label. `.Name` is a property for every control and returns the actual name of the element.

Comment: How do I do it that it goes horizontally on the worksheet?

Comment: Instead of `.Range()` use `.Cells(1, i)` the `1` is the row to paste in.